# New to Vuetify: try to add v-tooltip to a dynamic ouput

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

we have an array of alarms (item.activeAlarms[]) and if there is an active alarm, we want to be able to see the fullName (item.activeAlarms[].fullName) when we hover over the v-chip. If there is no alarm then a tooltip with "No Alarm" should be visible.

```
<template v-slot:[`item.activeAlarms`]="{ item }">
    <v-chip small label color="warning" v-if="item.activeAlarms.length > 0">
        <v-icon small left>mdi-alert-outline</v-icon>
        {{ item.activeAlarms.length }}
    </v-chip>
    <v-chip label small dark color="light-green" v-else>
        <v-icon small left>mdi-check</v-icon> Keine
    </v-chip>
</template>
```

The problem is when we add the v-tooltip as it is recommended (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tooltips/#api) it ended up showing us "[object Object],[object Object]" inside the v-data-table and not the "active" chip with state as before.

```
<template v-slot:[`item.activeAlarms`]="{ item }">
   <v-tooltip v-if="item.activeAlarms.length > 0" color="warning" bottom lazy>
      <template>                  
         <v-chip v-on="item" small label color="warning" @click="">
            <v-icon small left>mdi-alert-outline</v-icon>
            {{ item.activeAlarms.length }}
         </v-chip>
      </template>
      <span>Warning Tooltip</span>
   </v-tooltip>
   <v-tooltip v-else color="success" bottom lazy>
      <template>                  
         <v-chip label small dark color="light-green">
            <v-icon small left>mdi-check</v-icon> Keine
         </v-chip>
      </template>
      <span>No Alarm</span>
   </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

A working hard-coded static way would be looking like this:

```
<v-tooltip bottom color="success">
   <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-chip color="success" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
         No Alarms
      </v-chip>
   </template>
   <span>No alarms for this system</span>
</v-tooltip>
<v-tooltip bottom color="warning">
   <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
      <v-chip color="warning" dark v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
         <v-icon small left>mdi-alert-outline</v-icon>
         2
      </v-chip>
   </template>
   <span>Alarm: xxxx on this system</span>
</v-tooltip>
```

Hope someone can help us :-)

Comment: Hi Reginald, could you please provide an example showing how you tried to include v-tooltip?

Comment: Hey Iwolf, sure have added it now

Comment: Hey, can you provide a working snippet where we can see the `[object Object]` on the tooltip?

Comment: Sorry, seems like this was a problem on my site with caching seeing [object object] I have added a new static way of solving this but can't make it dynamic- if anyone can help me with this would be great

Comment: You can provide a little bit more code like `item.activeAlarms` to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

After some trial and error I managed to solve this little problem

```
<template v-slot:[`item.activeAlarms`]="{ item }">
   <v-tooltip v-if="item.activeAlarms.length > 0" bottom color="warning">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
         <v-chip color="warning" small dark label v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
            <v-icon small left>mdi-alert-outline</v-icon>
            {{ item.activeAlarms.length }}
         </v-chip>
      </template>
      <span v-for="alarm in item.activeAlarms" >{{ alarm.fullName }}</span>
   </v-tooltip>
   <v-tooltip v-else bottom color="light-green">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
         <v-chip color="light-green" small dark label v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
            No Alarms
         </v-chip>
      </template>
      <span>No alarms for this system</span>
   </v-tooltip>
</template>
```

Comment: you can accept your own answer if this solved your problem.